# Hive inefficient nested joins

Tags: hive

I have two large Hive tables (billions of records) that can be joined by a common key (i.e. the transaction ID). `table_a` contains all the transaction ID's, and `table_b` has transactions for some of the time.

[image]

In theory, there should be no duplicate transaction ID's in either table. In practice, there are a few duplicates and, while they're relatively few in number, the many:many join has potential to cause problems. I'm building a model based on this data and, as a first pass, it's probably easier to ignore all the records with duplicate transaction ID's.

I wrote an ugly Hive query that, although it logically does what it needs to do, it's horribly inefficient:

```
SELECT
   table_a.someCol,
   table_b.anotherCol,
   [etc...]
FROM
    (SELECT
       table_a.*
     FROM table_a
     INNER JOIN
       (SELECT
          transaction_id
        FROM table_a
        GROUP BY transaction_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) unique_transaction_ids
    ON table_a.transaction_id = unique_transaction_ids.transaction_id) table_a_unique_transaction_ids_only
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
       table_b.*
     FROM table_b
     INNER JOIN
      (SELECT
         transaction_id
       FROM table_b
       GROUP BY transaction_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) unique_transaction_ids
    ON table_b.transaction_id = unique_transaction_ids.transaction_id) table_b_unique_transaction_ids_only
ON table_a_unique_transaction_ids_only.transaction_id = table_b_unique_transaction_ids_only.transaction_id;
```

How it works:

First, for for both tables, create a list of transaction ID's that that only appear once:

```
SELECT
    transaction_id
FROM table_?
GROUP BY transaction_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Then filter the tables by inner joining the unique transaction subqueries to the original tables.

Finally, left outer join the filtered subqueries.

Is there a more efficient way to write this (e.g. using analytical functions such as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...`)?

Comment: How many column do you have in `table_a` & `table_b` ?

Comment: Both tables contain 37 columns which are predominantly strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `table_a` and `table_b` together, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` seems inevitable.  The two self-joins can be avoided.  Since you want `transaction_id`'s that have occurred only once, you can take `MAX()` or `MIN()` on the rest of the columns without loss of information (even if they are not numerical columns).  Something like

```
select transaction_id
  , max(col1) col1
  , max(col2) col2
        .
        .
        .
  , max(coln) coln
from table_a
group by transaction_id
having count(transaction_id) = 1
```

It's a way to "pull columns through" to the next "level" without having to `group by` them.  It can be tedious to write if you have a lot of columns but is usually worth it to avoid two self-joins.